# Marking a makefile dependency as optional or otherwise unimportant

Tags: makefile

I have a Makefile with a pair of rules like the following:

```
file.c: filesvn

filesvn: .svn/entries
     action1
     action2
```

Within the svn repository, this of course works fine.  The file is dependent upon living in a subversion repository.  When exported from the repository, this does not work (No rule to make target...), and I would like to fix that.  I have tried to simply bring a previously-generated version of `filesvn` out into the exported directory, but Make still insists on verifying `filesvn`'s dependency.

Simply deleting the dependency of .svn/entries does work, of course, but then the spirit of the rule is broken since watching for a revision update is the goal.

Is there a way to get Make to not care that the .svn/entries file is not there?

The merits of such a technique are not really part of the question.  I can't fundamentally change this, but if there is a change that maintains the spirit that might work.  An answer of "You can't" is perfectly valid of course. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a target that generates copy of actual makefile with changes that drop the svn dependency, run make with it and then deletes it.

Answer (score 31):

You can use the `wildcard` function to ignore the file unless it exists:

```
filesvn: $(wildcard .svn/entries)
```

Aside: Subversion 1.7 changes the format of the local working copy, so this rule would stop working even in working copies.

Comment: Also, if you need to use pattern rules inside a `wilcard` or other function, make sure to use secondary expansion (http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Secondary-Expansion.html).

Comment: This answers "optional if NOT exists", but for "continue if error" see: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53760185/8740349

Answer (score 3):

**Pattern `%` rules**

For pattern rules, you need `.SECONDEXPANSION`:

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:
%.a: %.b $$(wildcard $$*.c)
    cc $< -o $@
```

See also: [How can I make a pattern rule dependency optional in a Makefile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34105205/how-can-i-make-a-pattern-rule-dependency-optional-in-a-makefile)

Tested in Make 4.1.