# Makefile with optional dependencies

Tags: makefile, dependencies, option-type

I have some .c and .h files that are generated by a script based on one XML file and optionally another XML file.

From what I've read I should be able to use a wildcard, for example:

```
%Generated.c %Generated.h : %Compulsory.xml $(wildcard %Optional.xml)
   generation-script $< $*
```

The files XXXGenerated.c/h are being regenerated when I change XXXCompulsory.xml but not when I change XXXOptional.xml. Does anyone know why?

I can get around the problem with duplicate rules as follows:

```
%Generated.c %Generated.h : %Compulsory.xml
   generation-script $< $*

%Generated.c %Generated.h : %Compulsory.xml %Optional.xml
   generation-script $< $*
```

but I would have thought there was a better way to specify an optional dependency?

Thanks!

Note: This same question has been asked before (e.g. [How to manage C header file dependencies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9598595/how-to-manage-optional-dependencies) ) but in this case I can't have the compiler generate a .d file.

**Edit:**
The location for Optional.xml is fine because it works if I specify only the rule:

```
%Generated.c %Generated.h : %Compulsory.xml %Optional.xml
   generation-script $< $*
```

And try to compile only for a target which Optional.xml exists.

But I've noticed that doesn't work with the parenthesis:

```
%Generated.c %Generated.h : %Compulsory.xml $(%Optional.xml)
   generation-script $< $*
```

Comment: this should work, are you sure you are not confusing the location of Optional?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make a pattern rule dependency optional in a Makefile?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34105205/how-can-i-make-a-pattern-rule-dependency-optional-in-a-makefile) Voting to close this way because the other has the right answer.

Comment: @CiroSantilli709大抓捕六四事件法轮功 this was asked two years before that one - wish someone had mentioned that I just needed a second dollars sign! `$$(wildcard %Optional.xml)` probably would have worked.

Comment: @austinmarton yes... correct answers improve the world a little bit :-)

Comment: despite the age difference, please accept the duplicate flag so seekers find the answer more quickly

Comment: **Related:** [Marking a makefile dependency as optional](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8175653/8740349)

Answer (score 0):

when you use the function wildcard, the wildcard character is *, not %

($wildcard *Optional.xml)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work either, also tried $(wildcard *Optional.xml)