# Optional dependency in makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am trying to get an optional dependency in GNU make. I tried to use $(wildcard) but am getting un-expected output:

test.mk:

```
a:
        @echo "a"
b: $(wildcard a)
        @echo "b"
        @touch a
```

expected output:

```
$ make -f ./test.mk b
b
$ make -f ./test.mk b
a
b
```

actual output:

```
$ make -f ./test.mk b
b
$ make -f ./test.mk b
b
```

What am I missing about $(wildcard) ?

Comment: is `a` a file? Wildcard is used for patterns like `*.c` right?

Comment: Yes, "a" is a file and $(wildcard) is a GNU make function.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8175653/marking-a-makefile-dependency-as-optional-or-otherwise-unimportant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not missing anything about `$(wildcard ...)`. It's just that
file `a` already exists when you run `make b` for the second time, so
`make` doesn't need to make it and so isn't going to run its recipe.

If you add:

```
.PHONY: a
```

to the makefile then target `a` will be made, if required, regardless of the existence of such a file
and give the behaviour you expect, but it's not clear from your post if this would really capture your objective.

Comment: ah, that is obvious with hindsight. Thanks !